# Multiple Regex-replace (In Aptana Studio 3), depending on match

Tags: regex, aptana3

Since `mysql_*` is going deprecated, I was thinking of an easy way to replace all deprecated code.

Here is my regex; whereas `find` is what I want to find and `repl` is what I want to replace it with.

`$__db` is my declared `mysqli_connect`-variable

```
Change MySQL into MySQLi
--
find: mysql_select_db\(([\$"a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
repl: \$__db->select_db($1)
--
find: mysql_fetch_object\((\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
repl: $1->fetch_object()
--
find: mysql_fetch_array\((\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
repl: $1->fetch_array()
--
find: mysql_num_rows\((\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
repl: $1->num_rows
--
find: mysql_free_result\((\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\)
repl: 
--
find: mysql_query
repl: \$__db->query
--
find: mysql_error\(\)
repl: mysqli_error\(\)
--
find: ([\$a-zA-Z0-9_]+) = mysql_result\(([\$a-zA-Z0-9_]+), (\d+)\)
repl: \$row = $2->fetch_array();\r\n$1 = \$row[$3]
```

And my question would be, can I run multiple regex-replaces (so that I can replace all code at the same time)?

I know that I can use pipe `|` to separate the find-part, but how does it work with the replace-part?

I haven't found a way to make a macro in Aptana Studio 3.

Comment: No you can't search and replace different things in a single regex. At least not in your situation. Also please note that there is almost no meaning to go for mysqli if you aren't going to use prepared statements. My 2 cents: spend your time to manually update your code preferably by using PDO, it's really worth it. Don't forget to use prepared statements !

Comment: I do see the value of going to prepared statements, but much of the SQL written in the projects I'm "fixing" uses much too dynamic joins. But sure, the simple questions can easily be replaced with the prepared statements. I just want to avoid getting more code, when the queries are already sanitized. Right now, it is just a question on how fast I can get `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`.

Comment: My condolences ... Well if you insist then here's an idea: edit your PHP code with PHP ! **1-)** Loop through each directory/files **2-)** Write a custom function that does all your replacements.

Comment: You sir, are an angel. Please post that as an answer, so I can accept it. Why didn't I think of that? (Also include that you really should use manual labor, because it is better that way, since you can sanitize the queries better with prepared statements)

Comment: Well I should include code to do that but I don't have time at the moment for it. If you get it done, post the solution and accept it. It's possible :)

Comment: Ok. :) Will do! Thanks for your tips. I'll see if I can make the code create prepared statements for the queries I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This became my solution, with tips from [HamZa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401975/hamza) (Thanks!)

I created a script, that iterates over a directory of choosing (Specified in `$dir`)

We also get to say what we're looking for in the files with `$lookFor`

I added some comments in the code, so you can follow what I do. This **WON'T** solve `function`-db's though.

So if you have classes with DB-connections you'll have to add something for functions.

Right now this script won't change your files (I commented it out, so you can use it to just browse through your code with the *"recommended"* changes)

And also.. I haven't made it so the script prepares statements.

(That is step two, this was just to *fix* things that would break when `mysql_*` gets removed)

The result will look something like this: (Actually showing that missing function I talked about.. I'll have to add `global $__db;` into each `function`

[image]

And then finally! Here's the code.

```
<?
/*IGNORE-MYSQL*/
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) == $needle;
}
function doFlush()
{
    @flush();
    @ob_flush();
}

function runMySQLToMySQLi_replace($str, $useBoldShow = false, $replace = true)
{
    $catchVars = '\$"\'a-zA-Z0-9_\.\*\->,\[\] ';
    $regexTests = Array();
    $regexTests['(?:['.$catchVars.']+\s?=\s?)?mysql_connect\((['.$catchVars.']+),\s?(['.$catchVars.']+),\s?(['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '\$__db = mysqli_connect($1, $2, $3)';
    $regexTests['mysql_select_db\((['.$catchVars.']+)(?:,\s?['.$catchVars.']+)?\)'] = '\$__db->select_db($1)';
    $regexTests['mysql_query\((['.$catchVars.'\(\)=]+)(?:,\s?['.$catchVars.']+)?\)'] = '\$__db->query($1)';
    $regexTests['mysql_errno\(\)'] = '\$__db->errno';
    $regexTests['mysql_error\(\)'] = '\$__db->error';
    $regexTests['mysql_error\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '\$__db->error';
    $regexTests['mysql_fetch_object\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->fetch_object()';
    $regexTests['mysql_fetch_row\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->fetch_array()';
    $regexTests['mysql_fetch_array\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->fetch_array()';
    $regexTests['mysql_fetch_assoc\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->fetch_assoc()';
    $regexTests['mysql_num_rows\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->num_rows';
    $regexTests['mysql_free_result\((['.$catchVars.']+)\)'] = '$1->free()';
    $regexTests['mysql_insert_id\(\)'] = '\$__db->insert_id';
    $regexTests['(['.$catchVars.']+) = mysql_result\((['.$catchVars.']+), (\d+)\)'] = "\$row = $2->fetch_array(); $1 = \$row[$3]";
    $tmpVal = $str;
    foreach($regexTests as $reg => $rep)
    {
        $match = preg_match("/" . $reg . "/i", $tmpVal);
        if($match)
        {
            if($replace)
                $tmpVal = preg_replace("/" . $reg . "/i", ($useBoldShow ? "[{b}]" : "") . $rep . ($useBoldShow ? "[/{b}]" : ""), $tmpVal);
            else
                $tmpVal = preg_replace("/" . $reg . "/i", ($useBoldShow ? "[{b}]" : "") . "$0" . ($useBoldShow ? "[/{b}]" : ""), $tmpVal);
        }
    }
    return $tmpVal;
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .mysql_found { background-color: mistyrose; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #c9c9c9; border-radius: 5px; margin: 10px; }
        .no_select {
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: moz-none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none; 
            display: inline-block;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<pre><?
    // Directory to search in
    $dir = "/dir/to/search/in/";
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    // What we are looking for in all files
    $lookFor = "mysql_";
    foreach($objects as $name => $object)
    {
        // Ensure that it is PHP-files we're going through
        if(endsWith($object->getFilename(), '.php')) 
        {
            // Get all contents
            $contents = file_get_contents($object->getPathname());
            // Split it into rows
            $rowSplit = preg_split('/$\R?^/m', $contents);

            // Check the contents for $lookFor
            if(strpos($contents, $lookFor) > 0 && strpos($contents, "/*IGNORE-MYSQL*/") === false)
            {
                echo "<div class=\"mysql_found\">\"" . $lookFor . "\" found in: " . $object->getPathname() . "\n";
                echo "<hr noshade=\"noshade\" />\n";
                echo "Source code:\n";
                $lCount = 1;
                foreach($rowSplit as $row)
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"no_select\" unselectable=\"on\">" . str_pad($lCount++, strlen(count($rowSplit)), " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ": </div>" . str_replace(Array("[{b}]", "[/{b}]"), Array("<b style=\"background-color: #cfaaaa;\">", "</b>"), htmlentities(runMySQLToMySQLi_replace($row, true, false))) . "\n";
                }
                echo "\n\n";

                $lCount = 1;
                echo "Fixed code:<br /><br />";
                $doneCode = "";
                foreach($rowSplit as $row)
                {
                    echo "<div class=\"no_select\" unselectable=\"on\">" . str_pad($lCount++, strlen(count($rowSplit)), " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ": </div>" . str_replace(Array("[{b}]", "[/{b}]"), Array("<b style=\"background-color: #cfaaaa;\">", "</b>"), htmlentities(runMySQLToMySQLi_replace($row, true))) . "\n";
                    // This is the code that actually does the replacing.
                    $doneCode .= runMySQLToMySQLi_replace($row) . "\n";
                }
                // This is commented out, since I want to make sure it works before I accept some changes.
                // I actually tried it on 3 files without problems.
                //if(isset($_GET['Accepted']))
                //  file_put_contents($object->getPathname(), $doneCode);
                echo "</div>";
            }

        }
        doFlush();
    }
?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to ask me something about this code, do it. :)